# How to solve errors in If statements

Tags: java

When I try a nested if function, it only outputs the "else" part.Like in the code below. what can I do?

```
if (B==1)
{
    Classmate();
}
if (B==2)
{ 
    results()
} else
{
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Invalid choice");
```

Comment: `else if (B == 2) {` (instead of `if (B == 2)`). **Or** use a `switch` statement.

Comment: Please double check that the shown code is actually a [mcve] which demonstrates your problem. Because the code would do `Classmate();` AND `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Invalid choice");` in case of `B==1`. So it does not match the description 'only outpus "else" part'.

Comment: I took the liberty of cleaning up your indentation, to support analysis of the logic structure of your code. Feel free to undo it, my apology in that case. Also feel free to add a closing final `}`.

Answer (score -1):

**I am assuming in your code, your `if (b == 2)` conditional was meant to be nested.**

Your `{ }` brackets are not lined up properly. In order for a conditional if to be nested, it must be INSIDE of the other brackets.

*Based on that assumption...*

A nested conditional `if (b == 2)` will only run IF the first conditional is true (i.e. `if (b == 1)` ).

So to sum things up, if and only `if (b == 1)`, it will check `if (b == 2)`. `if (b != 1)`, then the `else` will run.

Hopefully that helps. Also look into styling guides on formatting lines. It will make your life easier in the long run. :)

```
if (B==1) {
    Classmate();

    if (B==2){ 
        results()
    }
}

else {
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Invalid choice");
}
```

Comment: @Yunnosch The underlying problem is the question itself. We have no implementation details of ```Classmate()```. For all we know it could set B equal to 2.  Who knows... I was more just giving him/her some information on the topic as the information is lacking here. (He also mentioned a nested if statement, but both of the if statements are outside of eachother)

Comment: If OP's intent was to have two non-nested conditionals, you would be correct. I'm unaware if he made a mistake in his code, or his question... his question mentions a nested conditional, but his code warrants otherwise.

Edit: What I'm saying is, we're bothing making assumptions. ;)

Comment: True. Assumptions on both sides. I have the advantage of the privilege to ask clarificatoin questions in a comment. You need to be brave and make an answer directly. My respect for that. Good luck. By the way, I made another assumption concerning the term "nested", but I do not express it here, because it would be hard to do that and keep up the polite impression.... So I simply focus on the code shown instead of the prose description.

Comment: May I recommend to explain your assumption that "nested" is the actual goal of OP? I.e. in contrast to understanding the shown code which is NOT nested. Showing then how a nested if construct would look like and how it behaves would be a helpful answer. The difference to your answer as it is is admittedly subtle but in my opinion important. Don't worry however, it is only my opinion.